# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects python

Tags: python

I have this python program

Function:

```
def populate_year(self, cursor, user_id, context=None):
    year_dropdown = ''
    for y in range(2010, (datetime.datetime.now().year + 10)):
        year_dropdown = year_dropdown + '(' + y, y + '),'
    return year_dropdown
```

Field:

```
'year': fields.selection(populate_year,'Year',select=True, required=True),
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().year` this is string. `10` is an int.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun `datetime.year` is an `int`. The `TypeError` comes from `'(' + y`, where `y` is an `int`.

Comment: Try to solve the problem before asking, especially when the program is small and simple. Here is some advice:

1. read error message and locate error line, understand [python errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).
2. use python/ipython interpreter to run your code interactively to test possible errors or solutions.
3. if all the above won't work, use pdb/ipdb debug tools to dig in running time.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the integer year to a string using `str` and then concatenate.

However, [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) would do the type coercion for you:

```
>>> '({year}, {year})'.format(year=2014)
'(2014, 2014)'
```

You can also join together strings with a separator:

```
>>> ','.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a,b,c'
```

Altogether:

```
this_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
year_dropdown = ','.join('{year}, {year}'.format(year=year)
                         for year in range(2010, this_year + 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 problems in this line:

```
year_dropdown = year_dropdown + '(' + y, y + '),'
```

One is that you used `... + ... , ... + ...` - did you want to use a plus sign there? Or quote the `,` part?

The other, which is where you see the error, is that `year_dropdown` is a string and `y` is an int. You can use `str(y)` instead in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use `str(y)` instead of `y` in for loop

```
for y in range(2010, (datetime.datetime.now().year + 10)):
                year_dropdown = year_dropdown + '(' + str(y), str(y) + '),' # use str(y)
```

`'(' + y, y + '),'` here you are concatinating `string` and `int` (y)

see what you doing 
at first iteration `y=2010`

```
'(' + 2010, 2010 + '),'
```

you are concatinating string with `y` which is an `int` value.

Comment: @iam supreeth check the solution.